# JSF problema no metodo de Logoff

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, front-end

Boa noite

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu tenho uma aplicação JSF e preciso fazer um comando de logoff, eu fiz varios e todos deram o mesmo resultado, ele "mata" o a sessão do usuário (faz o logoof), mas não redireciona para tela de login (que é tela que eu quero que ele volte) bom aqui está os códigos:

Esse é o ManageBean:

```
    public String logoff() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);  
    session.invalidate();   
    return "/pages/public/index.xhtml";     
}
```

E aqui o commandLink do XHTML:

```
<p:commandLink id="logoff" value="Teste"
                actionListener="#{autenticacaoManageBean.logoff}"  ajax="false" />
```

A tela de login e a tela que esta o botão logoff estão em pastas separadas

o login está em `pages/public/login.xhtml`

o botão esta em `pages/templates/header.xhtml`

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns pontos que devem ser considerados:

1. `actionListener`, use em casos onde precisa executar uma lógica relacionada a view, onde não há necessidade de troca de página.
2. A página que está retornando no método `logoff` não indica que é um redirecionamento, por padrão será feito o `page forward`.

Para componentes [Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/), use `action` ao invés de `actionListener`, quando há necessidade de troca de páginas.

Quanto ao seu método de `logoff`, para indicar ao JSF que há redirecionamento, adicione `faces-redirect=true` no retorno de sua página.

Bean:

```
public String logoff() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);  
    session.invalidate();   
    return "/pages/public/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";     
}
```

Chamada:

```
<p:commandLink id="logoff" value="Teste"
                action="#{autenticacaoManageBean.logoff}" ajax="false" />
```

Comment: valeu brother, deu certo aqui, muito obrigado.